# Docker container lamp/linode

Tags: docker, linode

Guys i just Docker Toolbox on my Windows 10 PC.

The lamp server is working fine but i just wanted to know how can i access the www folder which was created by linode lamp container ?

it is accessible via terminal but how can i access it in file browser so that i can create html files and run them.

I want to know how to access that var/www folder that they state in their tutorials on installing lamp.

I tried creating a file in that docker terminal using touch but could not access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `docker volume ls` you can find which are the volumes that are being used by the container. And now you can find the location of volume using `docker inspect <volume_name>`.

OR

You can inspect the container using `docker inspect <container_name>`. This will list out the details of the container and there you will find the paths which are being used as `volume` or `mounts`.

Usually in windows, the files of internal docker volumes are stored in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks`.